# I can't properly create a table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

Recently I'm having a problem: When creating a table, I can't do anything with the table. I can't see the list inside or anything. I just get `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)` when if there are rows. When I enter the table, I get `SELECT * FROM 'config'` and in Structure I get rows created. For example: I create 1 table with 1 row of the following:

**Image 1:**
[image: image 1]

**Image 2:**
[image: image 2]

I could create well a long time ago, but yesterday, before this happened to me, I was installing SQL but I didn't, I don't know if it's any of that. I need help is for my server

Comment: Have you SAVED your editions (commit transaction)?

Comment: No Akina, I didn't know I could do that. What's wrong?